# *Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest' android studio

Tags: android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXkdb.png)*Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4] C:\Users\bob.android\build-cache\ffee37ec2ebb9fa5949d9f876f8678567ce55e66\output\AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.ads.impl" to force usage*

Comment: what is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to add admobe to the source code